# Artificial webcam on windows

Tags: c++, window, webcam

I use v4l2loopback to generate a webcam in linux and I feed the virtual webcam with Opencv images.

I would like to do the same on Windows. I found this example:

https://github.com/rdp/open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter

When I try to compile it I get this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)      cannot open source file "streams.h" vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 23  
Error (active)      cannot open source file "olectl.h"  vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 24  
Error (active)      cannot open source file "initguid.h"    vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 25  
Error (active)      cannot open source file "dllsetup.h"    vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 26  
Error (active)      identifier "STDAPI" is undefined    vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 31  
Error (active)      identifier "CLSID" is undefined vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 31  
Error (active)      identifier "LPCWSTR" is undefined   vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 31  
Error (active)      identifier "LPCWSTR" is undefined   vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 31  
Error (active)      identifier "LPCWSTR" is undefined   vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 31  
Error (active)      identifier "LPCWSTR" is undefined   vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 31  
Error (active)      identifier "STDAPI" is undefined    vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 32  
Error (active)      identifier "CLSID" is undefined vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 32  
Error (active)      this declaration has no storage class or type specifier vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 37  
Error (active)      identifier "CLSID_VirtualCam" is undefined  vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 37  
Error (active)      expected a ')'  vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 37  
Error (active)      identifier "AMOVIESETUP_MEDIATYPE" is undefined vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 41  
Error (active)      identifier "MEDIATYPE_Video" is undefined   vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 43  
Error (active)      identifier "MEDIASUBTYPE_NULL" is undefined vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 44  
Error (active)      identifier "AMOVIESETUP_PIN" is undefined   vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 47  
Error (active)      identifier "FALSE" is undefined vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 50  
Error (active)      identifier "TRUE" is undefined  vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 51  
Error (active)      identifier "FALSE" is undefined vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 52  
Error (active)      identifier "FALSE" is undefined vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 53  
Error (active)      identifier "CLSID_NULL" is undefined    vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 54  
Error (active)      identifier "NULL" is undefined  vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 55  
Error (active)      identifier "AMOVIESETUP_FILTER" is undefined    vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 60  
Error (active)      identifier "CLSID_VirtualCam" is undefined  vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 62  
Error (active)      identifier "MERIT_DO_NOT_USE" is undefined  vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 64  
Error (active)      identifier "CFactoryTemplate" is undefined  vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 69  
Error (active)      identifier "CLSID_VirtualCam" is undefined  vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 73  
Error (active)      class "CVCam" has no member "CreateInstance"    vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 74  
Error (active)      identifier "NULL" is undefined  vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 75  
Error (active)      identifier "STDAPI" is undefined    vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 83  
Error (active)      identifier "BOOL" is undefined  vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 83  
Error (active)      identifier "HRESULT" is undefined   vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 85  
Error (active)      identifier "NOERROR" is undefined   vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 85  
Error (active)      identifier "WCHAR" is undefined vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 86  
Error (active)      identifier "MAX_PATH" is undefined  vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 86  
Error (active)      identifier "ASSERT" is undefined    vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 88  
Error (active)      identifier "g_hInst" is undefined   vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 88  
Error (active)      identifier "GetModuleFileNameA" is undefined    vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 90  
Error (active)      identifier "AmHresultFromWin32" is undefined    vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 91  
Error (active)      identifier "GetLastError" is undefined  vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 91  
Error (active)      identifier "MultiByteToWideChar" is undefined   vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 93  
Error (active)      identifier "CP_ACP" is undefined    vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 93  
Error (active)      identifier "lstrlenA" is undefined  vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 93  
Error (active)      identifier "NUMELMS" is undefined   vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 94  
Error (active)      identifier "CoInitialize" is undefined  vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 96  
Error (active)      identifier "CLSID_VirtualCam" is undefined  vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 99  
Error (active)      identifier "SUCCEEDED" is undefined vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 102 
Error (active)      identifier "IFilterMapper2" is undefined    vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 104 
Error (active)      identifier "fm" is undefined    vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 104 
Error (active)      identifier "CLSID_FilterMapper2" is undefined   vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 105 
Error (active)      identifier "IMoniker" is undefined  vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 110 
Error (active)      identifier "pMoniker" is undefined  vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 110 
Error (active)      identifier "REGFILTER2" is undefined    vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 111 
Error (active)      identifier "MERIT_DO_NOT_USE" is undefined  vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 113 
Error (active)      identifier "CLSID_VirtualCam" is undefined  vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 116 
Error (active)      identifier "CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory" is undefined    vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 116 
Error (active)      identifier "CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory" is undefined    vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 120 
Error (active)      identifier "CLSID_VirtualCam" is undefined  vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 120 
Error (active)      identifier "CLSID_VirtualCam" is undefined  vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 131 
Error (active)      identifier "CoFreeUnusedLibraries" is undefined vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 133 
Error (active)      identifier "CoUninitialize" is undefined    vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 134 
Error (active)      identifier "STDAPI" is undefined    vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 138 
Error (active)      identifier "TRUE" is undefined  vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 140 
Error (active)      identifier "STDAPI" is undefined    vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 143 
Error (active)      identifier "FALSE" is undefined vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 145 
Error (active)      identifier "BOOL" is undefined  vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 148 
Error (active)      expected a ';'  vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 148 
Error (active)      identifier "BOOL" is undefined  vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 150 
Error (active)      expected a ';'  vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Dll.cpp 150 
Error (active)      this declaration has no storage class or type specifier vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Filters.h   5   
Error (active)      expected a ';'  vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Filters.h   5   
Error (active)      not a class or struct name  vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Filters.h   8   
Error (active)      identifier "CUnknown" is undefined  vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Filters.h   14  
Error (active)      expected a ';'  vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Filters.h   14  
Error (active)      identifier "STDMETHODIMP" is undefined  vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Filters.h   15  
Error (active)      identifier "REFIID" is undefined    vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Filters.h   15  
Error (active)      identifier "IFilterGraph" is undefined  vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Filters.h   17  
Error (active)      identifier "LPUNKNOWN" is undefined vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Filters.h   20  
Error (active)      identifier "HRESULT" is undefined   vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\Filters.h   20  
Error (active)      cannot open source file "windows.h" vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\stdafx.h    12  
Error (active)      cannot open source file "SDKDDKVer.h"   vcam_vs_2010    c:\Users\seniordev\Desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\targetver.h 8   
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'SDKDDKVer.h': No such file or directory  vcam_vs_2010    c:\users\seniordev\desktop\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\open-source-directshow-video-capture-demo-filter-master\vcam_vs_2010_demo_video_capture_project\vcam_vs_2010\targetver.h 8
```

Most of the file in the error list can't be find in Windows folders.

How can I compile that project properly or where could I get an other windows virtual webcam example?

Comment: `cannot open source file "streams.h"` - so the file "streams.h" cannot be open-sourced on Windows plathform.

Comment: I saw that someone use CSourceStream class to generate virtual webcam. Where could I get a simple example?