# Partial import of pyvirtualcam, python 3.8 on windows

Tags: python, webcam

I want to set up a virtual webcam on windows.
Final aim being directing the output of OpenCV to meet (Say GMeet) frame by frame

**Steps Done**

A normal pip install showed the package not found.
I installed using the wheel distribution for python version 3.8.7 from [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/pyvirtualcam/#files).
I also installed OBS Studio, and OBS-VirtualCam 2.0.4. As mentioned in the installation guide [here](https://pypi.org/project/pyvirtualcam/#description).
I extracted the zip from the OBS-VritualCam release and could successfully start the virtualcam from the .dll file in the /bin/32bit directory by

```
regsvr32 /n /i:1 "obs-virtualsource.dll"
```

I could import pyvirtualcam!

But on running the code given with the package.

```
import pyvirtualcam
import numpy as np

with pyvirtualcam.Camera(width=1280, height=720, fps=30) as cam:
    while True:
        frame = np.zeros((cam.height, cam.width, 4), np.uint8) # RGBA
        frame[:,:,:3] = cam.frames_sent % 255 # grayscale animation
        frame[:,:,3] = 255
        cam.send(frame)
        cam.sleep_until_next_frame()
```

I get the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "pyvirtualcam.py", line 1, in 
> import pyvirtualcam
> File "D:\sem7\DSL\Project\try\pyvirtualcam.py", line 4, in 
> with pyvirtualcam.Camera(width=1280, height=720, fps=30) as cam:
> AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pyvirtualcam' has no
> attribute 'Camera' (most likely due to a circular import)

Sources:
[Capturing and manipulating a webcam feed and exposing it as a "virtual webcam" - in Python, on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63376473/10055814)

Answer (score 0):

Rename your file to something else than `pyvirtualcam.py` otherwise Python tries to import that one when you do `import pyvirtualcam`.